# Speech recognition / how to create TTS?

Tags: java

I have an idea to build program than can interact with  the user voice in Arabic language,  since one year ,I started with sphinx-4 but I need to make arabic acoustic model , grammar , dictionary. .
but I can't find the rood I want you to tell me in detailed description how to create those things?
the needed iIDE or program 
please help me....

Comment: Do you have hours of transcribed audio training data? I work in the speech processing field, and what you want to do is far from easy to do from scratch

Comment: I have audio record but I don't know what do you mean by transcribe audio data can you give me steps to make transcribe audio data please ...
and how to create language model

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me start at the very beginning, because I think you are not aware of the dimensions of your project, and you are mixing up things (ASR and TTS). First, I would like to explain what the different *things* are that you were talking about:

**Acoustic Model:** Every speech recognition system requires an acoustic model. Language, in particular words, are made up of phonemes. Phonemes describe how something *sounds*. To give you an example, the letter *a* is not always pronounced the same way, as you can see from the two words below:

to b**a**rk <=> to t**a**ke

Now your ASR system needs to detect these phonemes. To do this, it performs a spectral analysis of many short frames of the audio signal and computes features, like [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)s. What to do with these features? It puts them into a classifier (I could write a new chapter about the classifier here, but this will be too much information). Your classifier has to learn how to actually perform classification. What it does in simple words is it maps a set of features to a phoneme.

**Dictionary:** In your dictionary, you define every word that can be recognized by your ASR system. It tells the ASR the phoneme composition of a word. A short example for this is:

```
hello H EH L OW
world W ER L D
```

With this small dictionary, your system would be able to recognize the words *hello* and *world*.

**Language Model (or Grammar):** The language model holds information about the assembly of words for a given language. What does this mean? Think of the virtual keyboard of your smartphone. When you type in the words *'Will you marry'*, your keyboard might guess the next word to be *'me'*. That is no magic. The model was learned from huge amounts of text files. Your LM does the same. It adds the knowledge about meaningful word compositions (what everybody calls a sentence) into the ASR system to further improve detection.

---

Now back to your problem: You need transcribed audio data for the following reasons:

- You want to train your acoustic model if you have none.
- You want to create a large enough dictionary.
- You want to generate a language model from the text.

Long story short: You are wrong if you think you could solve all these tasks on your own. Only a reliable transcription is already a large amount of work. You should clearly overthink your idea.

Comment: thank you , yeah it's difficult but I believe I can do it
can I get your what's app number for more help in my project .

Comment: And i want you to tell me the required program to make acoustic model the steps any advices before I start and so for (Language model , Dictionary )